# Filter Results Using Query Parameter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to use the [@Param](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/Param.html) annotation for a custom query I built using Spring Data JPA's [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) such that when I pass the query parameter `?organizationId=2`, only Tasks will be returned that have an organization ID that match the given param.

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "tasks", path = "tasks")
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {

    List<Task> findByOrganizationId(@Param("organizationId") Long organizationId);
}
```

The problem is that when I visit the the `@RepositoryRestResource` path at `/tasks?organizationId=2`, it seems to be calling the default `List<Task> findAll();` method exposed at `/tasks`, and all Tasks are returned.

[image]

How can I make Spring direct the request to my custom method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All query method resources are exposed under the search resource. (See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.configuring-the-rest-url-path) for further information.)

`http://localhost:8080/tasks/search/` should give you the list of available search endpoints. One should be : `http://localhost:8080/tasks/search/findByOrganizationId`, to which you can apply your parameterized search.